# Viewpager displays only first fragment tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

First post on Stack so go easy on me...

Am trying to make an app where I have 4 tabs loaded up from a ViewPagerFragment, each tab is loading up a fragment. The first tab(let's call it Fragment A) gets data from online, saves it on a database then and then posts it on a listview, fragment B and the rest fetch from the database and post the data in their listview's too.

The first fragment displays the data perfectly on its listview but all the other fragments come up as blank..I have also noticed that if i don't put in the Fragment A and let the other tabs (B,C,D) load up from the already saved data in database, the data displayed will only be for the last tab(D) but it's data will be displayed on tab B..all the rest come up as blank.

Each Fragment starts the Network

Fragment A

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public static HomeFragment newInstance(String text) {
    HomeFragment mFragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putString("f", text);
    mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
    return mFragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getActivity();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    info = new Db(context);
    anime = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_up);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelist, container, false);


}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new NetworkClass().execute("0");
}


// -------------------------------xxx----------------------------
public class NetworkClass extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    //ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private InputStream is;
    private String result;
    MaterialDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //show loading...runs in main UI thread
        if (pre == 0) {

            dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .content(loadingMsg)
                    .progress(true, 0)
                    .show();


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


        //runs in background thread
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        HttpClient httpclient3 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost3;
        JSONObject jsonObject = getDetails();
        if (!SearchActivity.searchCheck) {

            Log.v("home post: ", "" + jsonObject);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonObj", ""
                    + jsonObject));
            httppost3 = new HttpPost(
                    "URL");

        } else {

            Log.v("Phone Details: ", "" + jsonObject);

            httppost3 = new HttpPost(
                    "URL");


        }




        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //stop refresh if any
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

        try {
            final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, inboxList,
                    R.layout.home_list_sub_layout, new String[]{}, new int[]{
                    R.id.title_TV_HLN, R.id.story_TV_HLN,
                    R.id.Date_TV_HLN, R.id.tonality_TV_HLN,
                    R.id.avatar_HLN, R.id.favImageView});

            list = (ListView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.home_list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            //change on refresh
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


            int x = adapter.getCount();
            Log.v("Count : ", "" + x);

            if (pre == 0) {
                //progressDialog.dismiss();

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            SearchActivity.searchCheck = false;



    }
}


private class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    int list_count;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                     int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);


        SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        String fetch = SP.getString("no_of_stories", "2");

        System.out.println(fetch);

        if (fetch.equals("1")) {
            list_count = 50;
        } else if (fetch.equals("2")) {
            list_count = 100;
        } else if (fetch.equals("3")) {
            list_count = 150;
        }

        //change on refresh
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    //no. of items to display
    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        System.out.println(list_count + " Check this out");
        return list_count;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_sub_layout,
                    null, false);
        }

        anime = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom : R.anim.down_from_top);
        convertView.startAnimation(anime);
        lastPosition = position;

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ViewPagerFragment

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

public List<TabPagerItem> mTabs = new ArrayList<>();
private HomeFragment home;

private int x = 0;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();
    createTabPagerItem();
}

private void createTabPagerItem() {

   mTabs.add(new TabPagerItem(getText(R.string.all), HomeFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.all))));

    mTabs.add(new TabPagerItem(getText(R.string.print), PrintFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.print))));
    mTabs.add(new TabPagerItem(getString(R.string.reports), MainFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.all))));
    mTabs.add(new TabPagerItem(getText(R.string.radio), RadioFragment.newInstance(getString(R.string.radio))));



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewpager, container, false);
    rootView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    //pages to store in memory
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mTabs));

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            (new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mTabs)).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    TabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mSlidingTabLayout.setElevation(15);
    }
    mSlidingTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


}
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<TabPagerItem> tabs) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.mTabs = tabs;

}

public void setDatasource(List<TabPagerItem> datasource){
    mTabs = datasource;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return mTabs.get(i).getFragment();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}

public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {

    return mTabs.get(position).getFragment();
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTabs.get(position).getTitle();
}
```

Fragment B,C,D...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    context = getActivity();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    info = new Db(context);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.homelist, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    MenuInflater flat = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
    flat.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_search:

            SearchDialog searchDialog = new SearchDialog(getActivity());
            searchDialog.show();

            break;
    }
    return true;
}



@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    new NetworkClass().execute("0");
}

public class NetworkClass extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        if (SearchDialog.iconChaeck) {
            searchDb = new SearchDB(context);
            searchDb.open();
            inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
            inboxList = searchDb.getData(arg0[0]);
            searchDb.close();
        } else {
            homeDb = new HomeStoriesDB(context);
            homeDb.open();
            inboxList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>();
            inboxList = homeDb.getData(arg0[0]);
            homeDb.close();
        }
        favouriteDB = new FavouriteDB(context);
        favouriteDB.open();
        favoritesList = favouriteDB.getFavoriteStoryIDList();
        favouriteDB.close();

        return inboxList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> result) {

        try {

            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, inboxList,
                        R.layout.home_list_sub_layout, new String[]{
                        "Title", "Story", "StoryDate",
                        "Media_House_ID", "tonality", "pic",
                        "favorite"}, new int[]{
                        R.id.title_TV_HLN, R.id.story_TV_HLN,
                        R.id.Date_TV_HLN, R.id.tonality_TV_HLN,
                        R.id.avatar_HLN, R.id.favImageView});

                list = (ListView) ((Activity) context)
                        .findViewById(R.id.home_list);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                //adapt.setDatasource(null);

                // ---------------------Click Event of List
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        int type = Integer.parseInt((String) inboxList.get(
                                position).get("Media_ID"));
                        switch (type) {

                            case 0:

                                Intent it = new Intent(context,
                                        PrintDetailActivity.class);

                                it.putExtra("map", inboxList.get(position));
                                startActivity(it);

                                break;

                            case 1:

                                it = new Intent(context,
                                        RadioDetailActivity.class);

                                it.putExtra("map", inboxList.get(position));
                                startActivity(it);

                                break;

                            case 2:

                                it = new Intent(context, TVDetailActivity.class);

                                it.putExtra("map", inboxList.get(position));
                                startActivity(it);

                                break;

                            default:
                                System.out.println("No form available");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Data Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
}

private class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                     int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_list_sub_layout,
                    null, false);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_TV_HLN);
        title.setText((String) data.get("Title"));
        title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date_TV_HLN))
                .setText("" + ((String) data.get("StoryDate")).replace(",", ""));

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.media_TV_HLN))
                .setText((String) data.get("Media_House_ID"));

        String mention_value = (String) data.get("mentioned");
        TextView mention = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.story_TV_HLN));
        if (mention_value == null || mention_value.equals("null")) {
            mention
                    .setText(Html
                            .fromHtml("<b><font color='#8c8c8c'>Mentioned:</font></b>"
                                    + " " + "N.A"));
        } else {
            if (mention_value.length() > 100) {
                mention_value = mention_value.substring(0, 99) + "...";
            }
            mention.setText(Html
                    .fromHtml("<b><font color='#8c8c8c'>Mentioned:</font></b>"
                            + " " + mention_value));
        }

        String tonality_value = (String) data.get("tonality");

        String two = "negative";

        if (tonality_value.equals(two)) {
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tonality_TV_HLN))
                    .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#AD0B11"));
        } else {
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tonality_TV_HLN))
                    .setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        }

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tonality_TV_HLN))
                .setText(Html
                        .fromHtml("<b><font color='#8c8c8c'>Effect:</font></b>"
                                + " " + tonality_value));

        ImageView storyIcon = ((ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.avatar_HLN));

        int media_id = Integer.parseInt((String) inboxList.get(pos).get(
                "Media_ID"));

        switch (media_id) {

            case 0:
                storyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_print);
                break;

            case 1:
                storyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_radio);
                break;

            case 2:
                storyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_tv);
                break;

            default:
                storyIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_print);
                break;
        }
        final ImageView imageview = ((ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favImageView));
        if (favoritesList.contains(inboxList.get(pos).get("Story_ID"))) {
            // Log.v(" favorit  story ", );
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_red);
        } else {
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_blue);
        }

        imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                favouriteDB.open();
                String story_id = (String) inboxList.get(pos).get(
                        "Story_ID");
                String msg = "";

                try {
                    if (!(favoritesList.contains(story_id))) {
                        favouriteDB.createEntry(inboxList.get(pos));
                        favouriteDB.close();
                        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_red);
                        favoritesList.add(story_id);
                        msg = "Successfully added in favorite list";
                    } else {

                        favouriteDB.deleteStoryID(story_id);
                        favoritesList.remove(story_id);
                        imageview
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.favorite_blue);
                        msg = "Successfully deleted from favorite list";
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    favouriteDB.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consecutive fragments belonging to a common ViewPager will load simultaneously. When are you loading data in the remaining fragments? It may be the case that Fragment B is loading alongside your Fragment A. But Fragment B loads before Fragment A's asynctask has completed?

Comment: They all load up at the same time but Fragment A takes longer, i can actually see the tabs being replaced one by one until the last one to be loaded remains, that is on the first tab..the rest remain blank..What should i do?

Comment: Remove the asyncTask from fragment A and get it to execute before the fragments with the viewpager is loaded. This way all data is available to your app prior to the fragments loading.

Comment: Tried to load the data immediately the app starts but it didn't work..I'm guessing it has something to do with my implementation of the other Fragments B,C,D..I have updated the code to show them..Check MyAdapter()...maybe am doing something wrong

Comment: Solved it!!.the problem was the Asynctask in the other tabs...Thanks